# How to clear a TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to clear my TextBox after clicking SEND?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace SocketClient
{

    public partial class SocketClient : Form
    {
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
        string readData = null;


        public SocketClient()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void getMessage()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                int buffSize = 0;
                byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
                buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
                string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                readData = "" + returndata;
                msg();
            }
        }


        private void msg()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(msg));
            else
                textDisplay.Text = textDisplay.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + readData;
        }


        private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            readData = "Conected to NYP Chat Server ...";
            msg();
            clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textName.Text + "$");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

            Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
            ctThread.Start();
        }


        private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textSend.Text + "$");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

            Send(textSend.Text);
            textSend.Text = "";

        }

        private void textDisplay_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textDisplay.SelectionStart = textDisplay.Text.Length;
            textDisplay.ScrollToCaret();
            textDisplay.Refresh();
        }

        private void textSend_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          Send(String text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're going to need to describe your situation more.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: ok my application is like the MSN.
after u press send the text in the textbox will be auto clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // send text
    byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textSend.Text + "$");
    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    serverStream.Flush();

    // clear textbox
    textSend.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: You should lock the empty string assignment since it isn't theard safe

Comment: This guy is trying to clear a text box. i think thread safety is probably not a concern.

Comment: @Hendrix: the answer seems pretty clear too. Not sure why all the down vote. Perhaps the simplicity of the question is throwing people? i suggest an up vote. Get the n00b out of the dog house.

Comment: i have an error after adding this line, saying that
the name 'send' does not exist in current context

Comment: @mk: `Send(string text)` is the method you have to write to send the text in the textbox. After it's sent, the textbox is cleared.